# Azure AD SAML with React and Nodejs - auto login with azure portal

Tags: active-directory, saml, saml-2.0, azure-ad-msal, azureportal

I'm new to SAML and Azure AD. I have worked with MSAL(Microsoft Authentication Library) but the requirement is different here.

What I am asked to do is - User is logged in to browser tab1 with https://portal.azure.com/ and the browser tab2 has opened my web app (***dummyexample.com***).
Now when the user reloads the browser tab2 *i.e.* my web app then the user should automatically log in as the user is already logged in to browser tab1 (in the Azure portal). If the user is not logged in tab1 then tab2 should redirect to login with azure credentials.

As much as I know it is not possible. How the tab2 reads the session/cookie of tab1? How ***dummyexample.com*** would know that the Azure AD is already logged in the browser? I am told that it's possible with SAML but I can't find any resources.

Could you please help me with the requirement?

Comment: I did it with the help of a passport-saml package. We need callback URL, entity, issuer, and cert which we'll get from the Azure admin. When the user hits the route(backend) it redirects to the azure to login and if the user has already been logged in then it redirects to the callback URL. This is a simple approach. We don't need to read the data/cookie/auth of tab1/tab2, what saml does it it redirects to the azure ad login page and checks whether the user has already been logged in or not.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your scenario and it is working for me.  You just need to configure your web apps to point to this Active Directory. Since authentication for web apps was moved to portal.azure.com.

[image]

Do the authentication setting as I have done.

Configure the 'Stay signed in?' prompt for Azure AD accounts or Azure portal
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/keep-me-signed-in

Now try to open the azure apps. Please watch the below GIF I have attach for your reference also.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgDyF.jpg